# Select using dynamically generated tablename

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the following problem. My table (`geo_table`) structure is as follows:

```
foreign_table_id | foreign_table_name | some_other_fields...
```

`foreign_table_name` stores names of different tables and `foreign_table_id` stores ids within these tables. What I want to do is check whether a row in the above mentioned table stores valid reference to some other table. Thus I need to select a row from foreign table which name is based on string stored in `foreign_table_name`. My code didn't work because it has syntax error but it clearly presents what I wanted to achieve:

```
SELECT foreign_table_id, foreign_table_name FROM `geo_table` gt
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gt.foreign_table_name AS t
    WHERE gt.foreign_table_id = t.uid
) > 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know all possible table names then you can implement it using conditional syntax:

```
SELECT foreign_table_id, foreign_table_name FROM `geo_table` gt
WHERE 
    CASE gt.foreign_table_name
        WHEN 'table1' THEN 
            EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM table1
                WHERE id = gt.foreign_table_id
            )
        WHEN 'table2' THEN 
            EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM table2
                WHERE id = gt.foreign_table_id
            )
        ELSE
            FALSE
    END
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be done dynamically :

```
declare @tablename varchar(50)
set @tablename = 'test'
declare @sql varchar(500)
set @sql = 'select * from ' + @tablename
exec @sql
```

Comment: Thank you so much. There is one thing I need to ask though. How do I place this code? At the beginning of the inner query?

Comment: this should be done dynamically! the only way to do the whole query is through a stored procedure