# Table Name stored in column used as part of query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I cant seem to find information related to this question.

I have four tables: `pages, items, linktable, datatable`

The pages table has a ID that links to the Items table.

The items table has an ID and Table Name field and ID that reference the table which has the actual data for the item.

**aka:**

```
Pages_Table:

pg_id
pg_title

Items_Table:

pg_id
item_type
item_id

link_table:

item_id
data_id
data_table_name
```

I need select data based on the data_table_name which varies, there are 10 different `data_tables`

I cant seem to find anything related to incorporating this into a SINGLE Query.

With multiple queries obviously not an issue.  Essentially its selecting a database table dynamically to be included in the query.

Comment: Discover [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: what did you did until now ? show some code !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938085/select-using-dynamically-generated-tablename

Comment: I think you are better off creating additional mapping tables for each relationship that you have.  That way you have a page_link_table and a item_link_table which you can directly query off of without having to do anything fancy.  I believe this will be more scalable and manageable in the future as well.

Comment: @Dan - So you are saying I am better off creating a separate link table for each item type and just statically query them per se. For example, lets for sake of argument say "items" are components.  One component just outputs vanilla HTML.  Another lets say does images. I should have a separate link table to for each item type and obviously a separate data table for each link table type?

Comment: What's the schema for each data table, and why do you have so many of therm?

Comment: The schema for each data table varies based on what components are loaded on a given page.  The PageID results in querying a user table, the users table has component assignment ID that references a table of component ID's for the given page/user. That is then used to obtain the data the various components are to use/render. Its a pluggable business management system. Given the range of components/data I felt it a good idea to keep the raw data generic to access and let the components deal with how to handle it.

Comment: For example,there is a HTML component, just grabs/renders HTML, a forms component, builds any form from DB data or XML, multipage etc. A Question/Answer (learning) component, a images component, a lightweight spreadsheet component, a charts component. Two databases, one being site specific, the other allowing shared data across sites on the same server or via authenticated REST. In some ways similar to a CMS but its for business management/education etc.

Comment: Its using PDO not that it "must".  There is an extra abstraction layer between the components and databases that makes any requests generic so the underlying data access the main application/components dont need know a thing about.  I am trying to keep DB querys to a minimum which of course depends on the underlying data management software be that Oracle, mySQL, SQLite, Postgres, Maria or even a flat file DB.

Comment: Optimally all data for all components would be pulled down in one query which is why making the data in as far as the DB is concerned generic is the way I've been looking at it. The portion that suffers in this design is searching.  But, towards that end I figured Tags table(s) could be used and then fallback to a more brute force method if tags search fails.

Comment: The framework coded up for this project was done from scratch.  Tried codeignighter, fuel, yii, Symfony in benchmarking design.  What we have is at its slowest 400% faster than any of the above. No MVC crapola ancient design patterns that are completely ridiculous to use for what amount to 95% linear applications flow. MVC makes sense in apps that have persistent mechanisms. Connections servers/daemons, DB daemons etc. Frameworks waste GOBS of time implementing patterns never meant for linear type app flows