# MySQL: How to select rows from a Child tablename composed of preset prefix and parent table field value without running multiple queries

Tags: mysql, dynamic, subquery

Assume I have three tables like so (the latter two are similar for the sake of clarity, but in reality, are not similar at all):

```
events
-------------------------------
| id | short | event          |
-------------------------------
|  1 | moo   | Cow Tipping    |
-------------------------------
|  2 | baa   | Sheep Shearing |
-------------------------------

registrants__moo
-----------------------
| id | name           |
-----------------------
|  1 | Dave           |
-----------------------
|  2 | John           |
-----------------------

registrants__baa
-----------------------
| id | name           |
-----------------------
|  1 | Carol          |
-----------------------
```

How would I execute the following query, such that the `???` in the subselect would be replaced w/ `short` such as `'moo'` or `'baa'` depending.

```
SELECT
    E.*
    (SELECT count(*) FROM `registrants_???`) AS `registrants`
FROM
    `events`
```

With the expected result of the final query being:

```
---------------------------------------------
| id | short | event          | registrants |
---------------------------------------------
|  1 | moo   | Cow Tipping    | 2           |
---------------------------------------------
|  2 | baa   | Sheep Shearing | 1           |
---------------------------------------------
```

I've tried variations on CONCAT [Like: SELECT count(*) FROM CONCAT(`registrants__`, short)) AS `registrants`) ] , but haven't had any luck. I'm assuming I'm missing something really simple and just can't see the solution. =\

Comment: The first thing most people will ask you is "Can you change your schema?"  It would probably be better to have a general `registrants` table with an `id`, `name`, and `event_id`, and then have an `event` table with an `id` and `event_name`, and, finally, replace the `event` field in the `events` table with an `event_id`.

Comment: Most times if I encountered multiple tables with the same structure, it should have been one single table. That said, you could either use a `UNION` or create a stored procedure that prepares dynamically the wanted statement and execute this.

Comment: Dynamic SQL. Losing the value of precompile.  Thus why people say don't do this and change your design.  You might be able to partition the table and achive similar results but not lose perofrmance but you better have a good reason for segregating the data this way... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-selection.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510490/sql-query-dynamic-table-name-in-for or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480429/how-to-select-from-dynamic-table-name or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938085/select-using-dynamically-generated-tablename

Answer (score 0):

If you can only use a single query and changing the schema is out, your only option is something like this:

```
SELECT
  e.id,
  e.short,
  e.event,
  COUNT(e.id) AS registrants
FROM
  events AS e
  LEFT JOIN registrants__moo AS moo
    ON e.short = "moo"
  LEFT JOIN registrants__baa AS baa
    ON e.short = "baa"
GROUP BY e.id;
```

If you have a ton of `registrants__` tables you're in for a very long query, but there's nothing you can do about it.  At least this way is shorter than using a bunch of `UNION`s.